# Dictionary in quanteda with logical/context rules (cf Wordstat's "Proximity Rules")

Tags: r, quanteda

Prior to using quanteda for text analysis I used Provalis Wordstat. When using dictionary methods, Wordstat allows the user to include in the dictionary both regular terms and proximity rules (e.g.: "Sudan" NOT NEAR "South_"; "Congo" NOT AFTER "Democratic_Republic_of_the_"). Is it possible to apply a similar feature in quanteda? Friends suggested that some exclusion rule via regex could work, but I wouldn't know how to implement it.

Though I am not very familiar with writing regex (or whichever option would make this feasible), my thoughts would be something in the lines of:

```
# example for dictionary with names of 2 african countries
africa_dict <- dictionary(list(algeria="algeria",
                             republic_of_the_congo=c("republic_of_the_congo", "congo_(NOT AFTER democratic_republic_of_the_)")))
```

Comment: I am aware of the problem. Implementing proximity rule is not easy but I have an idea. Please join our discussion at https://github.com/quanteda/quanteda/issues/1375